# I can't display Reactstrap components in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hi guys I'm new to Reactjs, I can run `<h1>Hello World </h1>` in App.js. But when I use `<Container></Container>` in `Reactstrap` even though I have done all the imports, I get a blank page in the browser. App.js is not rendered when I use `<Container></Container>`.I am not getting any errors either.

**App.js => rendered**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**App.js => not rendered**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Container>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
          </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5",
    "reactstrap": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Hey here it looks like react-scripts is low version.I upgraded it to 4.0.0 and added the following in package.json

```
,
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

**Problem solved, thank you.**

Comment: created a codesandbox works fine here https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-mirzakhani-z7wli?file=/src/index.js

Comment: yes it is true but why is it not working for me?

Comment: Hey! I replaced my dependencies with the ones in codesandbox and it started working. But I still don't really understand the problem. My everything was complete though.

Comment: Did you have bootstrap as dependency earlier?

Comment: Yes there was, I updated my question. Any chance of reviewing again?

Comment: YEY, thanks to you :)